strongSwan ipsec tunnel over wifi vs wired connection difference
I'm trying to use a tunnel as a client on Debian 12.
I have a router with a wired connection and wifi. All firewalls are disabled.
The tunnel can be successfully installed on both connections:
...
connection 'tunnel' established successfully

But I have problems connecting to some services in the tunnel. Ping is ok for both connections, but  services are not responding (http/https) to requests through the tunnel over a wired connection (with wifi all is ok).
I do not understand what else can be checked, why there is a difference in behavior between two types of connection to the same router
